# phpstorm "invalid git roots"

Tags: git, msysgit, phpstorm

I have checked out code from github. I have then gone to Version Control > Enable version control integration. I have selected git. I then get the error "invalid git root". Why could I be getting this error?

I am using msysgit 1.7.1 and phpstorm 2.1.

Comment: Getting the same error with PHPStorm 4.0.1 and Git 1.7.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Are submodules involved? This is usually why this error shows up. From the command line you can check if that's the issue:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Hope this helps.